# How can you change the length of the dial radius of a gauge that is already rendered?

Tags: highcharts

How can you change the length of the dial radius of a gauge that is already rendered?

something like this:

```
chart.options.plotOptions.gauge.dial.radius = (Math.random() * 200);
chart.redraw();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/noahpeters/NzxUa/

Comment: So, in your example, you want the guage arrow to randomly change size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, you have to set the options on the series item and mark the series dirty to tell Highcharts to redraw it.

```
function (chart) {
    setInterval(function () {
        chart.series[0].options.dial.radius = Math.random() * 200;
        chart.series[0].isDirty = true;
        chart.redraw();

    }, 3000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/NzxUa/1/

Answer (score 0):

Based on the source code for `highcharts.js` redraw method, I would suspect that what you've described is not possible. Only axes are updated when calling `redraw`. This is also noted in [the documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.redraw%28%29).

You could however redraw things yourself, but that might be a bit of overkill.